# The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, scope, instance

I've created a method in my application which creates a number of panels at runtime. Within the loop that creates the panels, I have created a panel MouseMove event which controls the position of a tooltip based on the position of the mouse pointer in any one of the panels created.

I'm getting this error when I compile, I appreciate that `pnlOverview` is a creation within a different constructor, but for the life of me I can't understand how I can reach the `pnlOverview` instance from within the event handler.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Here's just the code I think you need to look at:

```
    public void CreatePanels()
    {
        int PanelPosX = 50;
        int PanelPosY = 500;
        int LabelPosX = 10;
        int LabelPosY = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < (Convert.ToInt32(txtNoOfPanels.Text)); i++)
        {
            // Create a new panel, each with a unique label identifying the inspector

            Panel pnlOverview = new Panel();
            pnlOverview.Name = "InspectorPanel" + (i + 1).ToString();
            pnlOverview.Text = "Inspector Panel " + (i+1).ToString();
            pnlOverview.Location = new Point(PanelPosX, PanelPosY);
            pnlOverview.Size = new Size(1200, 180);
            pnlOverview.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            Controls.Add(pnlOverview);
            pnlOverview.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(newPanelPaint);

            // Create a MouseMove event for each panel created
            pnlOverview.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(pnlOverview_OnMouseMove);

            Label lblInspectorName = new Label();
            lblInspectorName.Name = "InspectorName" + (i+1).ToString();
            lblInspectorName.Text = " Inspector " + (i+1).ToString();
            lblInspectorName.Width = 100;
            lblInspectorName.Height = 13;
            lblInspectorName.Location = new Point(LabelPosX, LabelPosY);
            lblInspectorName.Size = new Size(82, 13);
            pnlOverview.Controls.Add(lblInspectorName);

            PanelPosY += 190;
        }
        return;
    }

    // Show a tooltip
    public void pnlOverview_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.Show("HELLO", this, new Point(pnlOverview.Left + e.X + 1, pnlOverview.Top + e.Y + 1), int.MaxValue);
    }
```

Comment: Which language / which compiler?

Comment: @Dan Pichelman: This is C#. But what version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: Looks like C# to me, but that's obviously an assumption.  If that's true I would recommend using the FlowLayoutPanel instead of trying to position your elements manually.

Answer (score 1):

`pnlOverview` won't be in scope in your MouseMove handler, because it is a local variable in CreatePanels().

`sender` should be the control you're mousemoving over, but you'll need to cast it to the appropriate type.

Comment: Thank you all. Took a little runnaging around but I've got it to work.

Comment: No one here want to actually say how to declare a control so that it can be accessed in another event?